# TFS-SharePoint integration

Tags: web-services, bcs, tfs

I am currently investigating how to push data from Team Foundation Server to SharePoint.

Are there any connections available out of the box? Any useful online references? Third party tools?

Comment: Have you thought about licensing? Everybody who is working with TFS data needs to have a license. There might be an exception for those who only create bugs and view their own created bugs: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13350

Comment: Pushing from TFS to SharePoint is actually rather unusual outside of the TFS/SP integration for dev purposes.  Can you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Ewald - You don't need CAL's to update work items - see here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/sharepoint2010programming/thread/2a16c549-a750-4fbc-97d0-1afafbf06de7

Comment: @Dave: I need to share some data with people who have SP access but not TFS access.

Comment: @Russel: the thread says that you don't need a CAL if you update work items you have created yourself! Updating work items created by others is not included.

Comment: Licensing is never a yes/no answer. :) Vicky Song explained (briefly) more about SharePoint CALs required, which the OP may already have assuming they have SharePoint rolled out. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/tfsgeneral/thread/c349efa2-0382-4217-8684-4ae5dc9889b0

Answer (score 2):

TFS can integrate with SharePoint by installing TFS on the SharePoint server (and installing the extension).

I have used it before and found it very valuable. It allow business users (non-devs) who may not have access to TFS to add work items/bugs etc. and check bug fix rates and do reporting.

This is an MSDN article about integrating TFS and SharePoint:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253177.aspx

Here is an MSDN blog article with some extra links:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsadmin/thread/4acefd21-725d-4107-ba9c-bdfa8fe54012/

Comment: [You don't need to install TFS on the SharePoint server, only the extension.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15348564/344022)

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question on the same topic - [TFS Project linking to sharepoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38121/tfs-project-linking-to-sharepoint-2010) and I have posted a response that may be helpful. The approach would be to access the internals of TFS via its object model.