# TFS Project linking to sharepoint 2010

Tags: tfs

I would like to have the ability to connect to TFS via sharepoint 2010 and extract specific details out of the tfs projects that would already exist. I have been doing a research and have come up with nothing other than the fact that tfs has a sharepoint portal.

Comment: What kind of data do you want to extract?

Comment: I want to extract the work items and make it an issue tracking list in sharepoint and also extract the source control and make it a code base repository.

Answer (score 1):

Team Foundation Server provides reporting capabilities that can show various indicators of your development life cycle (ALM) - [Creating Reports for Team Foundation Server 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730837.aspx). You can also customize the reports - [Creating, Customizing, and Managing Reports for Visual Studio ALM.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb649552.aspx)

**UPDATE:** While there are integration points between TFS and SharePoint, I think what you are seeking would need programmatic access to the internals of TFS and [Extending Team Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146) (via its object model).

Other examples that may be helpful in your case -

- [Extending Work Item Tracking by Using the Client Object Model for Team Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130347)
- [Work Item Samples (query, edit, create, etc).](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/TfsSdk/Wiki/View.aspx?title=WorkItemTrackingSamples)
- [Extending Version Control (accessing the repository).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130331)

Comment: I am wondering if i can try and connect to tfs database and build my queries from that source, or if tfs has a pre-built Cube

Comment: I have updated my response above based on your additional comments - I don't think SharePoint integration to TFS by itself would provide the answer. You'll need to access the internals of TFS via its object-model (programmatically).

Comment: I looked through your updated links and officially realized what i want to do i will have to be able to do development in SharePoint to accomplish this task (SharePoint programing), this is an area that I will have to get familiar with very soon, thanks for your help also.

Comment: sure.. this site will help you get started - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/default